# Recommended way to redirect to same view and perform server side code from a client side event in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I am having a hard time deciding on an appropriate way to Perform some server side functionality and then redirecting to the same View in my ASP.Net MVC project.

I am trying to call an Action after the selected index changed client side event of my combobox.

One way I can think of is to change the window.location to the url of my Action and pass the data i need via the query string like this

```
function SelectedIndexChanged(s,e)
{
  window.location.href = "/MyController/MyAction?" + s.GetValue();
}
```

I also see lots of people saying you should use jquery ajax for this

```
function SelectedIndexChanged(s,e)
{
  $.ajax({
  url: 'MyController/MyAction',
  data: { value: s.GetValue() },
  success: function(){
    alert('Added');      
  }
});

}
```

My Action looks something like this where i set some cookie values using the value and Set View bags values depending on the selected index.

```
    public ActionResult SelectedIndexChanged(string value)
    {
        //Do some processing 
        //Set cookie values
         SetViewBags(value);
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

Is there a better approach to accomplish my task, I am leaning more towards changing the location.href as it is simpler, but i'm not sure if this is good practice?

**EDIT**

To Clarify this Combobox is a Devexpress MVC extension so I will have to handle the "SelectedIndexChanged" client side event.

This Combobox is also on my layout page so it appears on every view in my project. So when it is changed i will need to to call the same Action no matter what page it is on

Comment: Firstly, if you are already using AJAX, why do you want to refresh the page?  In that case, just send whatever data you want to update your view with via JSON.  Secondly, if you want to refresh the page, why use AJAX?  In that case, just submit a form on change of your element (via javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I want to update the entire page so your suggestion of submitting the form is somewhat right. However this is all happening in my layout page so i don't want to submit the form as this would call the current Action for the current page, but i want to call a separate Action in another controller so whatever page this combobox is changed on, the same Action will be called.

Answer (score 1):

As you've indicated that your form is in your layout (not a view), I recommend you look at using a view partial.  Fortunately, MVC has already provided an example with their view partial (can't remember the name) that has the login and logout buttons.  If a user clicks logout, some javascript is fired and the form is submitted.  This will redirect the user; however, you could also send the original address (referrer) as a parameter to your server method and then redirect to that page afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use an Html.Action

```
function SelectedIndexChanged(s,e)
{
    @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", {optional route values})
}
```